# a leading whitespace before the result from regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am using a rule to get substring in python using regular expression. But I found some results will have a leading whitespace while some of them don't. I know I can remove the whitespace with .strip(). But I want to understand why the whitespaces are there. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Ex 1. (no leading whitespace).

```
import re
utterance = 'can i make a call to +21231313'
re.findall('[-|#|+]*[0-9]*[-\s]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*', utterance.strip())
```

result:

```
['+21231313']
```

Ex 2. (leading whitespace).

```
import re
utterance = 'can i make a call to -21231313'
re.findall('[-|#|+]*[0-9]*[-\s]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*', utterance.strip())
```

result:

```
[' -21231313']
```

Ex 3. (leading whitespace).

```
import re
utterance = 'can i make a call to 21231313'
re.findall('[-|#|+]*[0-9]*[-\s]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*', utterance.strip())
```

result:

```
[' 21231313']
```

Comment: This `[-\s]*` will match the space as it scans from left to right since the part before that is optional. Maybe insisting on at least one number before that will help: `[-|#|+]*[0-9]+` `+` instead of `*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In RE, `*` will check for 0 or more occurrences of the expression. So the space comes only for the last block of your regex where every other block is interpreted as empty. Take a look to the state machine:

[image: state machine with minus sign]

The last block(`[-\s\./0-9]*`) will accept any number of the listed symbols that includes `space` and the sign `-` but not `+`. If your expression has the plus sign, the result will be:

[image: state machine with plus sign]

Because the only block that accepts `+` is the first block, and there is not `space` in the first one. Because of that, if the regex recognize a plus sign, the match will not have any spaces.

Answer (score 1):

The first chunk of patterns can match an empty string, `'[-|#|+]*[0-9]*[-\s]*[(]{0,1}`.

What you may use is make digit matching part obligatory while making the hyphen/space pattern optional and wrap that with an optional group, `(?:[0-9]+[-\s]*)?`. Also, you may avoid the whitespace at the end of the match if you re-factor the last `[-\s\./0-9]*` pattern to `(?:[-\s./]*[0-9])*`.

Use

```
[-#+]*(?:[0-9]+[-\s]*)?\(?[0-9]{1,4}\)?(?:[-\s./]*[0-9])*
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BLCw25/1)

**Details**

- `[-#+]*` - zero or more `-`, `#` or `+`
- `(?:[0-9]+[-\s]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of 1+ digits and then 0+ hyphens/whitespaces
- `\(?` - an optional `(`
- `[0-9]{1,4}` - one to four digits
- `\)?` - an optional `)`
- `(?:[-\s./]*[0-9])*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - `[-\s./]*`  - 0 or more hyphens, whitespaces, `.` or `/`
  - `[0-9]` - a digit.